# Lead Formula for sending an email when converted

Tags: email, formula, process-builder, leads

I created a process builder flow that will send an email when a lead is converted in lightning.

I created a hidden formula on the lead field that pulls in all the ConvertedID's in one field and I use that field to send out my email. the formula works but the look is not what the users what to see. Everything is group together and it doesn't look like the generated email that is sent from salesforce when in classic view.
Here is my formula code:
HYPERLINK("Account:","https://test.salesforce.com/"&  ConvertedAccountId)+
HYPERLINK("Contact:","https://test.salesforce.com/"&  ConvertedContactId)+
HYPERLINK("Opportunity:","https://test.salesforce.com/"&  ConvertedOpportunityId)

I am trying to have it look like the attached picture. [image: salesfoce genrated email when converting leads in classic]

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the running user doesn't have permission to view data on converted leads. There is a special permission for that.

You might not want to give that permission to users (I wouldn't). Another way is to use this tool (https://gravitylab.nz/send-email-alerts-and-log-the-email/) and you could log the emails being sent. You could populate your own plaintext body without an email template which will run in the context of the flow and should hopefully work.

Comment: Or are you just worried about the look?

Answer (score 0):

Or are you just worried about the look? If so you missing the gaps and line breaks. Try and add +BR()+ between the hyperlinks. Eg.

```
HYPERLINK("Account:","https://test.salesforce.com/"& ConvertedAccountId)+
BR()+ 
"Contact:"+FirstName+" "+Lastname+
BR()
+HYPERLINK("Contact:","https://test.salesforce.com/"& ConvertedContactId)
```